# How to change Pagecontroller indicator color from default white?

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

http://apptech.next-munich.com/2010/04/customizing-uipagecontrols-looks.html

In the above url has some sample code for customizing UIPageControl's Looks...

In my application i want to change the pagecontrol indicator(dot) color to some other color instead of default white...I'm following the code that are given in the above link.But,i'm having doubt.

NSString* imgActive = [[NSBundlemainBundle] pathForResource:IMG_PAGE_ACTIVE ofType:nil];

NSString* imgInactive = [[NSBundlemainBundle] pathForResource:IMG_PAGE_INACTIVE ofType:nil];

what should i give for pathForResource:-------------.and where should i add the images for active and inactive pages and how to retrieve the image into application.

please give me some ideas to do this...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the two images to your project resources.
For example `dot_active.png` and `dot_inactive.png`.

```
NSString* imgActive = [[NSBundlemainBundle] pathForResource:@"dot_active" ofType:@"png"];
NSString* imgInactive = [[NSBundlemainBundle] pathForResource:@"dot_inactive" ofType:@"png"];
```

I use these two images:

[image: Active image] for the active dot

[image: Inactive image] for the inactive dots

**EDIT**

If you want to modify the size of the dots, maybe

```
for (NSUIntegersubviewIndex = 0; subviewIndex < [self.subviews count]; subviewIndex++) {
    UIImageView* subview = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:subviewIndex];
    if (subviewIndex == page) {
        [subview setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgActive]];
    } else {
        [subview setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgInactive]];
    }
    subview.frame = CGRectMake(/* position and dimensions you need */);
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: @Jilouc:Again one doubt.How can i increase the size of the dot...please give me some ideas for this also...Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Maybe if you customise the `setCurrentPage` method in `StyledPageControl` to modify the frame of each subview (I've edited the answer to show how, but I can't test for the moment)

Comment: Hai jilouc...Here,set frame for the subview we have to give x ,y,width and height position.I'm giving like this:subview.frame = CGRectMake(30,30,20,20); But,i don't know what should i give exactly for x and y position.Before scroll it shows correct(1st dot with active image and all other remaining dots has inactive image)At the time of scroll to next page it's not working...

Comment: @jilouc:now the dot size is increased by giving like this...subview.frame = CGRectMake(subview.frame.origin.x, subview.frame.origin.y, 10,10);but the only one issue is ,in my application there is one view has 4 buttons at the time of click on the first button it goes to another view that view has page control here first dot of page control has inactive image...Why it shows like that..all other pages are works fine...please help me out jilouc...Thank you...

Comment: I can't really help for the frame change since I haven't do it in my apps. If your first dot is inactive and should not, then set the current page to 0.